# remove few items from a list in kdb

Tags: kdb

Below is a list of tables

```
q)tables[]
`abc`def`j`l_data`l_data1`l_data2`s`t
```

I'm trying to remove few tables name from the list of table names, and failing miserably, after lot of effort could think of below code which is not providing expected output

```
(string each tables[])_/:(string each tables[])?("def";"l_data*") 
/ Trying to remove tables - def, all table names like l_data*
/ Expected output - `abc`j`s`t
```

Can't think of a solution using inter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 q) a where all not (a:tables[]) like/: ("def";"l_data*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively avoid the each right adverb and the all function by using except as such:

```
(tables[] where not tables[] like "l_data*") except `def
```

Also worth noting that the string conversions aren't necessary to use regex